# Can the setExperienceId method be deleted from LightningSelfRegisterController?

Tags: apex, community

### BACKGROUND

We have enabled Customer Community and allowed self-registration for external users. In addition, we added a little piece of custom logic to the  `LightningSelfRegisterController` apex class. You can see the code for both `LightningSelfRegisterController` and `LightningSelfRegisterControllerTest` when communities in your org are enabled.

```
global without sharing class LightningSelfRegisterController {

    public LightningSelfRegisterController() {

    }

// other code here

    @AuraEnabled
    global static String setExperienceId(String expId) {
        // Return null if there is no error, else it will return the error message 
        try {
            if (expId != null) {
                Site.setExperienceId(expId);   
            }
            return null; 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex.getMessage();            
        }        
    }  
}
```

### QUESTION

When it came to testing we observed that the test coverage for LightningSelfRegisterController was less than 75%, which is, well, weird. One of the methods that was not covered by tests was `setExperienceId(String expId)`. I couldn't find anything about it except a similar method was mentioned in the documentation for [Site Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm)

What purpose does this method serve and can I safely delete it from the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expId` represents a cookie value and is set whenever a page is loaded.

> The cookie is set when the browser loads the URLs with the *expid* values.

This value is used to implement dynamic login branding. Refer to the below excerpt from the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_security_auth_branded_login.htm):

> If you create custom login pages with Visualforce and Apex controllers, you can now control how your login page appears and behaves to users at run time. For example, you can specify which logo appears depending on whether the user is an employee or customer. Or you can invoke different registration processes or different consent flows. This change applies to both Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic.
>
> To implement the user’s dynamic login experience, retrieve the value of the Experience ID cookie (***expid***) stored in the user’s browser.

The `setExperienceId(String expIdValue)` method is used to let you handle any dynamic login experience if you are building. If not, you can simply ignore that method and have that even as an empty method for your test coverage purposes.

> Use setExperienceId when you’re implementing dynamic login experiences.

More details on the method on its [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm).